# missing package in MXE

Tags: c++, qt, mxe

I've made a C++ project in Qt. My app shows short video using QMediaPlayer and QVideoWidget. 
Everything works fine when I compile it in Qt. I'm a Linux user. The problems starts when I try to cross compile it in MXE.
I have got an error:

```
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: multimediawidgets
```

and

```
main.cpp:12:24: fatal error: QMediaPlayer: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile.Release:132: recipe for target 'release/main.o' failed
```

I've add

```
QT       += core gui multimedia multimediawidgets
```

in my .pro file.
I have noticed that there is no QMultimediaWidget in MXE package
[list](https://mxe.cc/#packages).

Is there any solution to fix this problem ?